# AS3 best performance for side scrolling games (scroll lagging)

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there anyone who can point me in any direction what causes the lagging in a very simple side scrolling engine?

Example here: http://grtest.hu/sidescroll/sidescroll.html
Source: http://grtest.hu/sidescroll/sidescroll.zip

Is this a frame buffer problem or something else? i really don't understand... it's so simple.
Or should i use gaming engines like Box2D, FlashPunk?

The code is:

```
import flash.events.Event

bg.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBG)
function moveBG(e:Event){
    e.currentTarget.y <= -500 ? e.currentTarget.y = 0 : e.currentTarget.y -=3
}
```

Comment: try using cacheAsBitmap = true for your bg clip. In that way flash don't have to recalculate the vector clip on each frame (bg.cacheAsBitmap = true). for all non rotating / scaling object, it's better to set  cacheAsBitmap as true. And it's better if you can access bg directy instead of e.currentTarget.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Binou!
In the game every moving object are cached as a Bitmap. ;)

Comment: As the fps it's not always stable it's sometime better to move objects in function of passed time instead of move them on each frame by fixed values if you want i can show you a little function to do that

Comment: Could help to look into using a delta time so you are not relying on a constant framerate. That's basically what those engines do.

Answer (score 1):

here a simple code exemple for geting the frame time and move your bg using it:

```
var lastTime  :Number = 0;      // keep the last frame time
var moveSpeed :Number = 3 * 60; // 3 pixels by frame at 60 fps

bg.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
bg.cacheAsBitmap = true;

function onEnterFrame( e:Event )
{
    var now         :Number = getTimer() / 1000;    // get time in seconds
    var frameTime   :Number = now - lastTime;       // calculate frame time using the last time and the actual time
    lastTime = now;                                 // saving the last time

    bg.y -= moveSpeed * frameTime;
    if( bg.y <= -500 )  bg.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for both of you, Binou and imcg!

I've implemented your approach into the code, too bad the problem still exist. As you can see here:
http://grtest.hu/sidescroll/sidescroll.html
, the rendering is not smooth(constant), at least for me.